# Is there an iterator-like pattern for parsing using recursive descent?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, data-structures, iterator

I have a recursive descent parser [here](https://github.com/grammarjs/recursive-parser/blob/master/index.js#L33):

```
Parser.prototype.parse = function(str){
  var val = this.visitExpression(str, this.grammar.root, this.grammar);
  this.reset();
  return val;
};

/**
 * Parse expression.
 *
 * @param {String} str
 * @param {Expression} exp
 * @param {Grammar} grammar
 *
 * @api private
 */

Parser.prototype.visitExpression = function(str, exp, grammar){
  var val;
  this.expression = exp;

  for (var i = 0, n = exp.rules.length; i < n; i++) {
    val = this.visitRule(str, exp.rules[i], grammar, exp);
    // blank string '' also counts
    if (null != val) return val;
  }
};

/**
 * Parse rule.
 *
 * @param {String} str
 * @param {Rule} rule
 * @param {Grammar} grammar
 *
 * @api private
 */

Parser.prototype.visitRule = function(str, rule, grammar, exp){
  var pos = this.pos;
  var args = [];
  var val;
  this.rule = rule;

  for (var i = 0, n = rule.symbols.length - 1; i < n; i++) {
    val = this.visitSymbol(str, rule.symbols[i], grammar, exp);
    if (null == val && rule.symbols[i].matchAndIgnore) {
      args.push(val);
      continue;
    }
    // if we didnt get a value, and we don't have a flag to skip if not match
    if (null == val && !rule.symbols[i].notMatchAndIgnore) {
      this.pos = pos; // reset
      return;
    }
    args.push(val);
  }

  return rule.apply(this, args);
};

/**
 * Parse symbol.
 *
 * @param {String} str
 * @param {Symbol} symbol
 * @param {Grammar} grammar
 *
 * @api private
 */

Parser.prototype.visitSymbol = function(str, symbol, grammar, parentExp){
  this.symbol = symbol;
  if (symbol.isExpression) {
    return this.parseExpression(symbol, str, grammar, parentExp);
  } else if (symbol.isString) {
    return this.parseString(symbol, str);
  } else if (symbol.isRegExp) {
    return this.parseRegExp(symbol, str);
  }
};

/**
 * Parse expression.
 *
 * @param {Symbol} symbol
 * @param {String} str
 * @param {Object} parser
 * @api private
 */

Parser.prototype.parseExpression = function(symbol, str, grammar, parentExp){
  var prev = this.expression;
  var exp = grammar.rules[symbol.expression];
  if (!exp) throw error("Expression '%s' is undefined (referenced in '%s')", symbol.expression, parentExp.name);

  if (symbol.many) {
    var pos = this.pos;
    var res = [];
    var val;

    while (val = this.visitExpression(str, exp, grammar)) {
      res.push(val);
    }

    this.expression = prev;

    if (symbol.onePlus && !res.length) {
      this.pos = pos;
      return;
    }
    return res;
  } else if (symbol.optional) {
    var res = this.visitExpression(str, exp, grammar) || '';
    this.expression = prev;
    return res;
  } else {
    var pos = this.pos;
    var res = this.visitExpression(str, exp, grammar);
    if (res && symbol.matchAndIgnore) {
      this.pos = pos;
      res = null;
    }
    this.expression = prev;
    return res;
  }
};

/**
 * Parse string.
 *
 * @param {Symbol} symbol
 * @param {String} str
 * @api private
 */

Parser.prototype.parseString = function(symbol, str){
  if (symbol.val === str.substr(this.pos, symbol.val.length)) {
    this.pos += symbol.val.length;
    return symbol.val;
  }
};

/**
 * Parse RegExp.
 *
 * @param {Symbol} symbol
 * @param {String} str
 * @api private
 */

Parser.prototype.parseRegExp = function(symbol, str){
  if (symbol.many) {
    var pos = this.pos;
    var res = [];

    while (symbol.pattern.test(str.charAt(this.pos))) {
      res.push(str.charAt(this.pos));
      this.pos++;
    }

    // reset if we want to match one or more but didn't find matches.
    if (symbol.onePlus && !res.length) {
      this.pos = pos;
      return;
    }

    return res.join('');
  } else if (symbol.pattern.test(str.charAt(this.pos))) {
    return str.charAt(this.pos++);
  } else if (symbol.optional) {
    return '';
  }
};
```

It's relatively simple as I could muster at the time. But I'm wondering nowadays if there is a way to simplify this and make it use a sort of *iterator* like you would see when implementing iteration. For example, with an iterator you can traverse a **list**, a **tree**, and a **graph** all the same way, without worrying about their unique oddities and implementation details.

```
for (var item of iterator) { ... }
```

Nice and simple. I would like to now apply this to parsers, but can't quite read [this code](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1599):

```
class sequence_parser implements parser {
    list parsers;
    iterator parse(iterator input) {
        foreach(p, parser) {
            input = p.parse(input);
        }
        return input;
    }
}

class choice_parser implements parser {
    list parsers;
    iterator parse(iterator input) {
        foreach(p, parser) {
            iterator output = p.parse(input);
            if (output != null) return output;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class loop_parser implements parser {
    parser other;
    iterator parse(iterator input) {
        input = other.parse(input);
        return parse(input);
    }
}
```

I can't imagine how it would handle backing up if it fails down a particular path, and stuff like that. Any ideas how to do this or if it's possible? What is the interface required basically, like the iterator example?

Comment: See: [Definite clause grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar)

Comment: "For example, with an iterator you can traverse a list, a tree, and a graph all the same way, without worrying about their unique oddities and implementation details." Trees and especially graphs are not linear datastructures; there is more than one way to [traverse them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), and you typically choose different orders for different analysis passes. Furthermore, most analyses examine subtrees, not just node. The only use case I can think of where a simple linear traverse would be the answer is syntax highlighting...

Comment: ...which requires iterating just over leaf nodes. You could do that with a depth-first traverse, but you need to ignore the non-leaf nodes during the traverse. So, all in all, it's hard to see how you could do what you suggest without wrapping parse tree into an awkward straitjacket. Of course, YMMV.